# SpringBoot + Hibernate JPA Lazy fetching mode still queries lists in an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

I am doing a REST API using springboot and JPA.
I am trying to lazy fetching an entity in a One to Many relationship. Teacher to courses.
I can see the sql statements done by JPA as I have the debuging option on.

In the controller, when calling a path all works great, but I can see that JPA is executing two queries. One for the teacher and another one for its courses. As I know, the lazy loading does not query until the data is required and I am not requiring it.

I have checked and conirmed that in the controller, when I retrieve the teacher data JPA does not query for the courses, but AFTER the return statement of the controller, somewhere, the courses are required and it loads everything when I call the teacher info from postman with a GET call.

It seems as if the LAZY loading is working correctly, but after the controller JPA loads the course list. If I do the EAGER fetching everything is loaded before the return statemnt.

I am not writing any code as I guess the question is more theorical than practical.

Does anyone know how this works?

Thank you so much!!!!

EDIT:

Teacher table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="profesores")
public class Profesor implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "profesor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Curso> cursos = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Course Table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "curso")
public class Curso implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long curso_id;

    private String nombre;

    @Column(name="profesor_id")
    private Long profesorId;
}
```

Controller

```
    @GetMapping("/profesor/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getProfesor(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id){
        Profesor p = profesorService.findById(id);
        if(p!=null) {
            ResponseEntity<?> re = new ResponseEntity<>(p, HttpStatus.OK);
            //Just one query executed. I don't know the courses yet
            return re;
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

After the return re; statement, somewhere, the courses are retrieved and JPA queries for them. I don't know what does the controller call, as I do directly from PostMan.

Comment: Show you code, depends on what annotations you have used, hibernate will fetch it eagerly or lazily.

Comment: @PriyakDey done. What I am thinking is that when you return an Entity all its values are queried, and the solution could be a mapper to send just what I want to send? Does it make sense? I though that if I did not call the courses, an empty array should have been passed.

Comment: As soon as the entity returned gets serialized its properties get accessed and the lazy relations get loaded. Since you don´t get a LazyInitializationException I believe you have the spring.jpa.open-in-view property set to true so there is still an open session to the database so your properties get successfully fetched.

Comment: please add `sql statements done by JPA `  also.

Comment: @AbinashGhosh here you have.
2020-04-02 09:04:32.912 DEBUG 5900 --- [nio-8044-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select profesor0_.id as id1_1_0_, profesor0_.create_at as create_a2_1_0_, profesor0_.email as email3_1_0_, profesor0_.foto as foto4_1_0_, profesor0_.nombre as nombre5_1_0_, profesor0_.password as password6_1_0_ from profesores profesor0_ where profesor0_.id=?

Comment: @AbinashGhosh ant the one done after the return statement. 
2020-04-02 09:04:33.023 DEBUG 5900 --- [nio-8044-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select cursos0_.profesor_id as profesor3_0_0_, cursos0_.curso_id as curso_id1_0_0_, cursos0_.curso_id as curso_id1_0_1_, cursos0_.nombre as nombre2_0_1_, cursos0_.profesor_id as profesor3_0_1_ from curso cursos0_ where cursos0_.profesor_id=?

Comment: @C.Weber is that wrong? should I change something?

Comment: To understand what I mean you can read the following article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After returned Entity `Profesor` is serialized for response when serializer try to access `courses` to serialized for response then JPA load `courses` also. To solve this issue, You can create a response class for response (without `courses` field)

```
public class ProfesorResponse {
    private Long id;
    private String number;
    ...constructor
}
```

then map your entity in response object and return it.

```
Profesor p = profesorService.findById(id);
ProfesorResponse response = new ProfesorResponse(p.getId(), p.getNumber());
```